# How does -a command line option in grep work?

Tags: command-line, grep

I am trying to learn to use the `grep` command.

I am not able to access the `-a` option and understand how it works.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `grep` will show if a binary file matches the pattern, but will not show the matched lines; would simply say e.g.:

```
Binary file /filename matches
```

But when you use `-a`, `grep` would show the matched portions, not the above message.

Here is a task for you:

```
grep bash /bin/bash
grep -a bash /bin/bash
```

Comment: I didn't get what you explained.....can you please elaborate this.