# auth.log regarded as a binary file

Tags: log

I tried to review the auth.log with grep

```
user@hos:~$ sudo grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log
Binary file /var/log/auth.log matches
```

It prompts auth.log is  a binary file, but

```
user@host~$ sudo tail -n 3 /var/log/auth.log
Jan 24 15:19:53 assistant sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by assistant(uid=0)
Jan 24 15:19:53 assistant sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 24 15:20:04 assistant sudo: assistant : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/assistant ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -n 3 /var/log/auth.log
```

When come to cat

```
user@host:~$ sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Why auth.log is regarded as a binary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
--binary-files=TYPE
      If  a  file's  data or metadata indicate that the file contains binary data, assume
      that the file is of type TYPE.  Non-text bytes  indicate  binary  data;  these  are
      either  output  bytes  that  are improperly encoded for the current locale, or null
      input bytes when the -z option is not given.
```

So the log file may be corrupted, or some application might have written non-text bytes to the file.

Also see:

- [How does -a command line option in grep work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881036/how-does-a-command-line-option-in-grep-work)